# I cannot stay logged in to a site with my router

Tags: networking, router, login

I have a D-Link home router and my isp is Time warner. When I try to login to any site it does not let me. The website does not keep me logged in when I navigate the pages. I have to keep loging in for every web page I see. When I connect my cable modem directly to my computer I am able to stay logged in. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like something in the security tab of your router setup is stopping site session info like cookies from passing through.  Try and go into you router config, look for something like a security tab and check the settings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your browser settings. Make sure your browser it set to accept and store cookies.

This problem has nothing to do with your router, but your browser settings.

Comment: Hello, Yes my browser is allowed to accept cookies. When I bypass my router and connect directly to my computer I have no problems and able to login to any site.